# Ask someone to wait a little longer in email

Tags: expressions

My customers send me emails asking me when I can fix their problems.
    In that case, I usually use expressions as below.

-Could you wait a little longer please?
-Could you be more patient please?
-Could you continue to be patient please?

Could you let me know they are common expressions?
I googled them but couldn't find many results using the same expressions.

If you have any other suggestions, it would be very helpful.
 Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi Chris, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find a little basic. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: Writing advice may be off-topic on ELU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in your searching, you have simply been unlucky. I searched for a few slightly different phrases including "Could you please be more patient with us", and found a large number of hits.

Your wording seems to me polite and unambiguous although I think that a native British English speaker would be more likely to place the word "please" after "could you". That would result in "Could you please be a little more patient", or "Could you please be patient a while longer".

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> "Could you wait a little bit more?"
>
> "Mr X I appreciate your patience, I'm just finishing your task."

You can also merge them.